# I want to know a condition to select user, nice, system and idle jiffies

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu

/proc/stat file has a user jiffies, nice jiffies, system jiffies, idle jiffies and so on.

I want to know a condition to select user, nice, system and idle jiffies.

What kernel file has a such information?

Comment: Umm... Didn't you just say that `/proc/stat` has exactly what you want to select? As in "`/proc/stat` has X, Y and Z. I want to know how to find X, Y and Z". In other words, your question is not very clear...

Comment: um.. sorry.. this question was insufficient.because i'm not fluent in English. I know that jiffies is up a particular term (maybe... 1/100 sec) so, one of them(user, nice, system, idle... and so on) increases every 1/100 sec. then I would like to know the conditions that increase one of them. ex ) if (instruction > 100) { user_jiffies++ ;}  else  { idle_jiffies++; }

Answer (score 0):

The structure and content of the special files under `/proc` is described in the [`Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) file, found in the Linux kernel source code.